# TradingView Pinescript Bug

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

```
    first_red_bar_index = ta.barssince(close < open)[1] + 1
    
    second_red_bar_index = ta.barssince(close < open)[first_red_bar_index
    + 1] + first_red_bar_index + 1
    
    first_green_bar_index = ta.barssince(close > open)[1] + 1 second_green_bar_index = ta.barssince(close > open)[first_green_bar_index + 1] + first_green_bar_index + 1
    
    x = bar_index y = high // txt1 = str.tostring(second_red_bar_index) // label.new(x, y, txt1, color = color.white, textcolor = color.black, size = size.large) txt2 = str.tostring(second_green_bar_index) label.new(x, y, txt2, color = color.yellow, textcolor = color.black, size = size.large)
    
    HHV = ta.highest(high, second_red_bar_index)[1] LLV = ta.lowest(low, second_green_bar_index)[1]
    
    sell = low < LLV 
buy = high > HHV
plotshape(sell, title = 'Sell', text = "SELL" , textcolor=color.black,  style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size= size.normal, color=color.black)
plotshape(buy, title = 'Buy', text="BUY", textcolor=color.black, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size= size.normal, color=color.black)
```

I'm expecting a label on every bar. However, on some bars there is no label. How can I fix this?

Comment: Describe what the code is supposed to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Logic I am trying to implement is to 

sell if the low of the current running candle is below the low of the first previous green candle as well as below the low of the second previous green candle

buy if the high of the current running candle is above the high of the first previous red candle as well as above the high of the second previous red candle

I have modified the code to reflect this in the below solution I have posted.

However, the code compiles successfully without any errors or problems but it does not successfully draw on the chart and gives an exclamation error.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_red_bar_index = ta.barssince(close < open)[1] + 1
second_red_bar_index = ta.barssince(close < open)[first_red_bar_index + 1] + 1

first_green_bar_index = ta.barssince(close > open)[1] + 1
second_green_bar_index = ta.barssince(close > open)[first_green_bar_index + 1] + 1

// x = bar_index
// y = high
// txt1 = str.tostring(first_red_bar_index + second_red_bar_index)
// label.new(x, y, txt1, color = color.yellow, textcolor = color.black, size = size.large)
// txt2 = str.tostring(first_green_bar_index + second_green_bar_index)
// label.new(x, y, txt2, color = color.yellow, textcolor = color.black, size = size.large)

// *****  Code Not properly working  ***** //
sell = low < low[first_green_bar_index + second_green_bar_index] and low < low[first_green_bar_index]
buy = high > high[first_red_bar_index + second_red_bar_index] and high > high[first_red_bar_index]
```

I tried to fix it as above.
However, the bug is with these sell and buy lines:

low[first_green_bar_index + second_green_bar_index]
low[first_green_bar_index]

high[first_red_bar_index + second_red_bar_index]
high[first_red_bar_index]